# jQuery setting checkbox state after preventing default action

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a checkbox that needs to change state, but without invoking parent's click event. So, I created this:

```
$("#divTabBody@(Model.TabNumber) tr input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    else
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

Parent's click is not execcuting, so that's good, but the checkbox is not changing state. Why?

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` is why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just use `e.stopPropagation()` to stop parent's click event. Nothing else needed.

```
$("#divTabBody@(Model.TabNumber) tr input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function(e) { 
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```